# Where does an IIS website store "precompiled site updatable" information?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, configuration

In order to be able to update certain files on an IIS ASP.NET website like `.aspx` files, you need to publish it with the "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" option selected in the advanced precompile settings dialog in Visual Studio.  However, what about after the site has been published?  Where is this setting stored?  What if I published a website with that setting off, but I want to enable it?  Do I have to republish the whole site?  In any case, where is that setting stored?

Answer (score -1):

That setting is not stored anywhere, and after pre-compilation it is lost. If you published a site with that setting off, you will have to republish so as to have it on.